# How to change System.out property temporarily

Tags: java, jsp

I want to change the System.out.property to textarea so that the user using my web app can see  the output on the Textarea at the same time when the code is executing on Textarea.

Till now I have copied the process InputStream on Textarea showing the output.
Now I want the code to be executed on the Textarea which can interact with user.

Should I change the System.out property for this purpose,or is there any other procedure to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `System.out` to go somewhere else (temporarily or otherwise), use:

```
System.setOut(sonePrintStream);
```

But that would output *all* output there, not just the output relevant to the user's interaction. Better to capture the relevant output another way and display it to the user. One way to do that would be to pass a callback to the code generating the output, which directs output to the user or System.out depending on what is passed in.

Comment: I executed the java code in my web-app on cmd and copied the process's InputStream and showed it to the user but that doesn't work if I use Scanner or some user interaction program.So I thought that changing the System.out property would be best option for me.